# How to use high and low bytes?

Tags: c++, byte, arrays, bit, 16-bit

I am trying to represent 32768 using 2 bytes. For the high byte, do I use the same values as the low byte and it will interpret them differently or do I put the actual values? So would I put something like
32678 0   or    256 0? Or neither of those? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? An unsigned short is 16-bits in c++, and would store numbers up to 32767.

Comment: Homework, eh? :) Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system Bytes are nothing but groups of eight bits.

Comment: I am trying to send a iRobot Create a command to drive straight. It says a value of "32768 or 32767" will make it drive straight. It takes in a high byte and low byte. The best I have gotten (in terms of driving straight) is 255 128, but that still turned some.

Comment: @Mike Bantegui A signed short stores numbers up to 32767, an unsigned short goes up to 65535.

Answer (score 31):

In hexadecimal, your number is 0x8000 which is 0x80 and 0x00. 
To get the low byte from the input, use `low=input & 0xff` and to get the high byte, use `high=(input>>8) & 0xff`.

Get the input back from the low and high byes like so: `input=low | (high<<8)`.

Make sure the integer types you use are big enough to store these numbers. On 16-bit systems, `unsigned int`/`short` or `signed`/`unsigned long` should be be large enough.

Comment: Or `unsigned short`. Generally better to use `unsigned` types with the `>>` operator.

Comment: Only because two bytes are involved is it wise to assume that the 16-bit boundary will not be broken. Generally though, bit shift operators work just find with `signed` integers and the choice to go unsigned should have more to do with whether or not negative values are required.

Comment: `short` is large enough that 32768 may overflow to -32768, and `int` may be the same size as `short`. Thus the value of `32768 >> 8` is implementation-defined.

Comment: Actually, this conversation is irrelevant. I just noticed that the question is tagged 16-bit. Updating my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 5):

Bytes can only contain values from 0 to 255, inclusive. 32768 is 0x8000, so the high byte is 128 and the low byte is 0.

Comment: You have a lot of reputation, but it's still not true that a byte always is exactly 8 bit wide. That, btw, is also the reason why in protocol specifications often the name "octet" is used as opposed to "byte". There are still systems around where a byte can have a size bigger than 8 bit. Also see Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: Fair enough. But I think I could count the number of modern systems that have a byte defined as something other than 8 bits on one hand.

Comment: true true. I reckon in practice this often won't matter, but I think one should know the distinction. And since the question of the OP is a very basic one, I think it would be worth to mention that in an answer.

Comment: Always with the zebra. Horses people, horses.

Answer (score 4):

Try this function. 
Pass your Hi_Byte and Lo_Byte to the function, it returns the value as Word.

```
WORD MAKE_WORD( const BYTE Byte_hi, const BYTE Byte_lo)
{
     return   (( Byte_hi << 8  ) | Byte_lo & 0x00FF );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pointers can do this easily, are MUCH FASTER than shifts and requires no processor math.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733170/4932683)

BUT:
If I understood your problem, you need up to 32768 stored in 2 bytes, so you need 2 unsigned int's, or 1 unsigned long. 
Just change int for long and char for int, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

32768 is 0x8000, so you would put 0x80 (128) in your high byte and 0 in your low byte.

That's assuming unsigned values, of course.  32768 isn't actually a legal value for a signed 16-bit value.

Answer (score 0):

32768 in hex is 0080 on a little-endian platform. The "high" (second in our case) byte contains 128, and the "low" one 0.

Comment: This is unhelpful and confusing. It introduces a second property of the bytes, relative order in memory, and fails to explain it as well as the high-order/low-order property mentioned by OP.